# Open book decompositions of $T^3$

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, 3-manifolds

Please pardon my ignorance on the subject of open books, I'm a noob.  I would like to know some explicit descriptions of open book decompositions of the three torus $T^3$.  Are there examples with connected binding?

Is there a direct topological proof that shows that every 3-manifold admits an open book decomposition?  Ideally, such a proof might start with a Heegaard decomposition or a surgery description of a given 3-manifold, and then proceed to give an algorithm for converting this to an open book decomposition.  In such a case, I suppose I could then follow such a proof to answer my first question regarding $T^3$.

Comment: Patrick Massot has some amazing videos of open books of $T^3$ on his webpage: https://www.math.u-psud.fr/~pmassot/en/exposition/giroux_correspondance.html For the other questions I would suggest Entnyre's notes on open books.

Comment: For an explicit example of an OB on $T^3$, you could take as page $\Sigma_{g=1,b=2}$ and monodromy $\tau_1^{-1}\tau_2$, where $\tau_i$ is a boundary Dehn twist for the two boundary components. Any open book can be stabilized: this yields one with $\Sigma_{g=2,b=1}$, hence with connected binding.

Comment: Ken Baker also has some nice visualizations of an open book on $T^3$. https://sketchesoftopology.wordpress.com/2008/11/24/the-jvhm-open-book/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a direct proof of exactly what you ask for on page 147 of:

*Calegari, Danny*, Foliations and the geometry of 3-manifolds, Oxford Mathematical Monographs; Oxford Science Publications. Oxford: Oxford University Press (ISBN 978-0-19-857008-0/hbk). xiv, 363 p. (2007). [ZBL1118.57002](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1118.57002).

Here Calegari provides the details of a well-known construction. Starting from the Heegaard splitting data of a fixed manifold $M$. He explains how to build a fibered link complement $M-L$.  Here $L$ is the complement of the set of curves used in Lickorish's theorem (showing every manifold is Dehn surgery on a link) plus one more 'unknotted' curve.

Calegari then answers your second question using the well-known technique of "plumbing along a Hopf band" find a new fibered link complement $M-L_1$ in $M$ with 1 fewer cusp than $M-L$. This comes at the expense of raising the genus of the fiber, but can be repeated until $M-L_n$ has just one cusp. Of course, this corresponds to an open book decomposition of $M$ with a connected binding.

If you are only interested in the case of $T^3$, you can start with the Borromean Rings (pictured here)[image: Borromean rings] as your fibered link (see Rolfsen's Knots and Link 338 for info on a fibration of this link complement). (0,1) surgery on each component yields $T^3$ and run Calegari's argument or use one of the two examples in the comments.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in a comment, [Ken Baker has a nice visualization](https://sketchesoftopology.wordpress.com/2008/11/24/the-jvhm-open-book/) of an open book decomposition of $T^3$ due to Jeremy Van-Horn Morris.

[image]

One way to get open book structures is to start with a fibered universal knot or link, and then pull back the open book structure from $S^3$ to a branched cover which is branched over that link. The [Whitehead link, the Borromean rings,](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=747855) and the [figure 8 knot](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=816529) are all fibered links that are known to be universal.

In fact, [every open book decomposition](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1078219) of a 3-manifold pulls back as a branched cover of $S^3$ of the standard open book decomposition of the unknot.